# Advice on large queries using AWS Api Gateway / Lambda / Athena

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-athena

So at the moment I am providing an ODATA endpoint to lots of large datasets. Tables can get quite large with some having lots of columns as well. We allow our clients to query that with an ODATA endpoint. At the moment things are okay but large results seem to take a while to save to S3.

So when running the query, I can eliminate query execution as when I save the results to a table its pretty fast. Now I have done some checking an unfortunately there is no way (as far as I am aware) to compress the results into S3 or split the files to see if that speeds it up.

Question I have is: Is there an ideal way to do this? Would an alternative data store be better? We are using apigateway so we are restricted to 30 second timeouts. It would be better if the data store we use provides an execution id for polling.

Any advice is welcome, thanks.

Edit: My mistake i said lambda when i meant API gateway having a 30 second limit.